# increase /opt in solaris

Tags: solaris

I have a solaris 10 VM. Its hard disk size is 10gb.
In the file system, I have checked the /opt size is around 635mb.
So my concern is can I increase the /opt size to 1GB. If so how can I achieve that ?

Please help me.

Comment: This isn't a programming question. http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: Yes, you can do it, but with non-programming tools. Hence I'm nudging this over to SF where you'll get a more targeted set of answers.

Answer (score 1):

You're using Solaris 10 so I assume you're on zfs. Assign another disk to your host or create another zfs file-system with fault tolerance of your choice.

Mount it under an arbitrary mount, say /opt-new. Stop any processes using /opt if you can, and recursively copy the contents to your new file-system.

At this point, definitely stop any apps using /opt. Move it out the way, say /opt-old and set your mountpoint for your zfs filesystem mounted on /opt-new to /opt.

Restart apps and confirm everything is well. Delete /opt-old once you are happy you do not need a roll-back.

Answer (score 0):

Yes this can be done if you have (or can create) the additional space on another disk or slice.

In general terms

- Identify/create/obtain the additional space and note it's device name.
- Use `metainit` to create a new md device that contains your existing  /opt and the new device
- unmoun the existing /opt
- edit your `/etc/vfstab` and create a new entry for /opt using the new md device
- mount the new /opt
- use growfs to expand the new /opt into the additional space `growfs -M /opt /dev/md/rdsk/<newdevice>`

You should have a look at the solaris man page for `growfs` which provides some more detail.